# "In order to run a story file you need to first set a main class in the JBehave settings" in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, jbehave, thucydides, jbehave-maven-plugin

i'm using intellij for the first time to work with jbehave. i have imported a pre existing maven jbehave project in to my intellij IDE. when i'm trying to run it using "Run Story" command. i'm getting the error "In order to run a story file you need to first set a main class in the JBehave settings"

could someone tell me why i'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

looks like you should set your project first.

First of all ensure that imported artifact is ok: run it from command line. Command should be something like `mvn verify serenity:aggregate`. If everything is ok (test complete and report created) then you need to set up your ide.

1. file → project structure. Is project sdk set?
2. Run → edit configuration. Not sure how it should look like for jbehave artifact, i'm using simple «serenity-junit».

   1. in upper left corner click green «+» sign, look for «junit»
   2. configuration tab → «Test kind» option = class
   3. configuration tab → «Class» option = select your test class (should have @RunWith annotation)
   4. save
   5. (optional) enable tool bar (view → toolbar) debug panel should be now visible and your class should be selected → now you can run this project from ide.

PS creating correct configuration for your project might be not that simple as i described, because you are using different artifact, but key is in this setting.

Comment: I don't have any @RunWith in my project; how does thucydides determine which class(es) to run?